# colorbox size based on odd or even page

Tags: tcolorbox, double-sided

I am trying to change the size of a colorbox based on inner vs. outer pages (odd vs. even). The commented code works, but it looks good only on odd pages. The code below that is (obviously) wrong, but it expresses that I'd like to change the four horizontal size parameters depending on whether the page is odd or even.

Thanks in advance for your help!

```
\documentclass[twoside]{scrbook}
\usepackage[outer=2.25in, inner=.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{ifthen,ifoddpage}
\SetBgContents{}

% this code runs
% \newtcolorbox{graybox}[1][]{#1,enhanced,width=5in,left=0cm,right=-2cm,extrude left by=1cm,extrude right by=3cm,colback=black!10!white,fontupper=\footnotesize}

% doesn't work but the sort of thing I want
\newtcolorbox{graybox}[1][]{#1,enhanced,width=5in,
    \checkoddpage
    \ifoddpageoroneside
      left=0cm, right=-2cm, extrude left by=1cm, extrude right by=3cm,
    \else
      left=-1cm, right=0cm, extrude left by=2cm, extrude right by=1cm,
    \fi
    colback=black!10!white,fontupper=\footnotesize}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-3]
\begin{graybox} \lipsum[1] \end{graybox}
\lipsum[3-4]
\begin{graybox} \lipsum[1] \end{graybox}
\lipsum[5-6]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As seen on [Tcolorbox Package Manual](http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf) on page 107, you can use the `if odd page`. I have created a code with `\newenvironment` instead of `\newtcolorbox`.

```
    \documentclass[twoside]{scrbook}
    \usepackage[outer=2.25in, inner=.75in]{geometry}
    \usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
    \usepackage{background}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \usepackage{ifthen,ifoddpage}
    \SetBgContents{}
    
    \newenvironment{mytcb}[1]
    {
    \begin{tcolorbox}[if odd page={enhanced,width=5in,left=0cm, right=-2cm, extrude left
 by=1cm, extrude right by=3cm,colback=black!10!white,fontupper=\footnotesize}
    {enhanced,width=5in,left=-1cm, right=0cm, extrude left by=2cm, extrude right
 by=1cm,colback=black!10!white,fontupper=\footnotesize}]
    #1
    \end{tcolorbox}
    }
    
    \begin{document}
    \lipsum[1-3]
    \begin{mytcb}{\lipsum[1]}  \end{mytcb}
    \lipsum[1-3]
    \begin{mytcb}{\lipsum[2]} \end{mytcb}
    \lipsum[1-3]
    \begin{mytcb}{\lipsum[3]} \end{mytcb}
    
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. However, the code works only when the box is on odd pages, but crashes for boxes on even pages ("TeX capacity exceeded [input stack size=5000]").

Comment: Update -- I found the error, which was a newline character between the two {}{} fields. Backspacing fixed the problem. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @ferahfeza I don't see the reason for a `newenvironment` instead of a `newtcolorbox`. It's just `\newtcolorbox{mytcb}{if odd page={....}}`.

Comment: @Ignasi thanks, your suggestion is simpler and easier because now I don't have to encase the text inside {}.